# Determine MATLAB's Monitor in a multiple monitor configuration

Tags: matlab, position, matlab-figure, multiple-monitors, matlab-gui

I move around from a company site to another a lot.  At any given day, I might have just my laptop or as many as four monitors. With multiple monitors, I don't know which monitor I will choose to use for MATLAB main GUI (the main GUI launched when double-clicking matlab.exe). It depends on the resolutions of the available monitors.

I use scripts that utilize programmatically generated GUIs (not by GUIDE) and it seems that MATLAB pops them up always on the first monitor. I've researched a little bit and found to locate the GUIs to a monitor of choice by using `p = get(gcf, 'Position')`, `set(0, 'DefaultFigurePosition', p)`, and `movegui` command, but this will only work if I know beforehand which monitor I want to use.

Is there a way to find out on which monitor the main MATLAB GUI is up and have other little GUIs pop up on the same monitor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use some Java tricks to get the current monitor; see code with comments below:

```
function mon = q37705169
%% Get monitor list:
monitors = get(groot,'MonitorPositions'); % also get(0,'MonitorPositions');
%% Get the position of the main MATLAB screen:
pt = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices.getEditorApplication.getActiveEditor.getComponent.getRootPane.getLocationOnScreen;
matlabScreenPos = [pt.x pt.y]+1; % "+1" is to shift origin for "pixel" units.
%% Find the screen in which matlabScreenPos falls:
mon = 0;
nMons = size(monitors,1);
if nMons == 1
  mon = 1;
else
  for ind1 = 1:nMons    
    mon = mon + ind1*(...
      matlabScreenPos(1) >= monitors(ind1,1) && matlabScreenPos(1) < sum(monitors(ind1,[1 3])) && ...
      matlabScreenPos(2) >= monitors(ind1,2) && matlabScreenPos(2) < sum(monitors(ind1,[2 4])) );
  end
end
```

Few notes:

- [Root properties documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.root-properties.html).
- An output value of "0" means that something's wrong.
- There may be an easier way to get the "RootPane"; I've used a method with which I have good experience.
- This will only recognize one of the monitors in case your MATLAB window spans several monitors. If this functionality is required you can use `com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices.getEditorApplication.getActiveEditor.getComponent.getRootPane.getWidth` etc. to find the other corners of the MATLAB window and do the same test with them.
- I didn't bother with breaking out of the loop after the first valid monitor was found since it is assumed that: **1)** Only one monitor is valid. **2)** The overall amount of monitors the loop will have to process is small.
- For the brave, one can perform a check with polygons (i.e. [`inpolygon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html)).

Comment: Updated link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.root-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

Thnx Dev-iL, works almost perfectly, i added some margins to 'catch' the window when slightly offscreen, or as in my experience,  simply maximized.
posting my edit:

```
   function mon = getMatlabMainScreen()
%% Get monitor list:
monitors = get(groot,'MonitorPositions'); % also get(0,'MonitorPositions');
%% Get the position of the main MATLAB screen:
pt = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices.getEditorApplication.getActiveEditor.getComponent.getRootPane.getLocationOnScreen;
matlabScreenPos = [pt.x pt.y] + 1; % "+1" is to shift origin for "pixel" units.
%% Find the screen in which matlabScreenPos falls:
mon = 0;
nMons = size(monitors,1);
if nMons == 1
  mon = 1;
else
    marginLimit = 100;
    margin =0;
    while ~mon
        for ind1 = 1:nMons
            mon = mon + ind1*(...
                matlabScreenPos(1) + margin >= monitors(ind1,1) && matlabScreenPos(1) < sum(monitors(ind1,[1 3])) + margin && ...
                matlabScreenPos(2) + margin >= monitors(ind1,2) && matlabScreenPos(2) < sum(monitors(ind1,[2 4])) + margin );
        end
        margin = margin + 1;
        if margin > marginLimit
            break;
        end
    end
end
```